# Appends '#' in the URL

Tags: angularjs, url

How to redirect the page in AngularJS without adding an `#` in the url?

Here is what I'm doing

```
$location.path('Clients/Edit/' + data.UserId);
```

so my url looks like this:

```
http://localhost/Clients#/Edit/1234
```

I just simple wants to have something like this: WITHOUT #

```
http://localhost/Clients/Edit/1234
```

Comment: did you set 
```$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)``` ?

Answer (score 2):

Please try in your html file set the base url:

Client side:

and in your location provider set as this:

```
$routeProvider
  .when('/path', {
    templateUrl: 'path.html',
  });
$locationProvider
  .html5Mode(true);
```

Server side:

Try to add in the .htaccess file following url rewrite:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    # HTML5
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*) /#/$1
</IfModule>
```

Then the url will display without the hash. Hope this will help.

Comment: Can you please also mention that the server hosting the app will need to be updated so that typing in the direct url will work.

Comment: Could you please help specify what needs to be updated on the server? You mean the apache config?

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location#server-side "Using this mode requires URL rewriting on server side, basically you have to rewrite all your links to entry point of your application (e.g. index.html)". How you do it will depend on what technology you are using to serve the angular application